# "Currency rates" or "currencies rates"

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english

What is the correct form when we have a rate for each currency in a list of currencies. For example if currencies are EUR, GBP and USD there will be a rate (buy and sell) for each one of these currencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Currency rates" is the preferred form. Personally, I would say that it is the only correct form, but Google does return about 15,000 hits for ["currencies rates"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22currencies+rates%22) (vs. 1,600,000 hits for ["currency rates"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22currencies+rates%22)).

**Edit:** seeing that your question is tagged "British English", I searched the [British National Corpus (BNC)](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) and got the following results:

```
   4 - currency   rates
   1 - currency   rate
   0 - currencies rates
   0 - currencies rate  (actually, 1, but "rate" is being used as a verb)
```

Also, as [Noldorin suggests in his answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/currency-rates-or-currencies-rates/3563#3563), there is the more popular term "exchange rate", for which Google returns 12,400,000 hits and BNC offers the following stats:

```
1192 - exchange rates
 408 - exchange rate
```

And, for the sake of completeness:

```
  14 - foreign    exchange rates
   6 - foreign    exchange rate
   4 - currency   exchange rate 
   2 - currency   exchange rates
   0 - currencies exchange rate
   0 - currencies exchange rates
```

Comment: Handy stats there. Sort of confirms what I knew/thought, but good to have them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The usual term is *exchange rate*. If you want to be unambiguous, say *foreign exchange rate*.